# Path for bib file: working simultaneously in TexStudio and Overleaf

Tags: bibtex, texstudio, overleaf

I have a project with several tex files in different folders, all of which use the same `bib` file that is in the parent folder:

```
ref.bib
Folder1 -> file1.tex
Folder2 -> file2.tex
...
```

I compile the tex files with TexStudio. Inside the tex files, I can reference ref.bib as follows:

```
\bibliography{../ref}
```

However, my colleagues work in Overleaf. There, for some reason, this does not work, and they have to reference it as follows:

```
\bibliography{ref}
```

Probably, TexStudio looks for bib files in the folder of the current tex files, while Overleaf looks for them in the root of the current project.

The `bib` file changes frequently, so duplicating it to the different folders is not a good option.

Is there a way to make this work on both TexStudio and Overleaf?

NOTE: I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\bibliography{ref}` and locally set BIBINPUTS enviornment variable to the parent directory but perhaps simpler would be to use

```
\bibliography{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\jobname}{output}=0 ref\else ../ref\fi}
```

as Overleaf always sets the jobname to output

Comment: This works, thanks a lot :-)